# Any case of midrash contradicting Tanakh?

Tags: torah-study, midrash, contradiction

I believe that most Midrash stories were used for homiletic lessons that shouldn't be taken literally and according to some writers, midrash has some contradictory statements and opinions about the same incident or person. In other words: cases of Midrash vs Midrash.

But when it comes to Midrash vs Tanakh, is there any case of midrash contradicting the Tanakh?

For example: Tanakh tells that "the woman X was the daughter of the man Y" while a midrash tells that "this same woman was his only wife" instead.

Or Tanakh tells that the man X, died by means of execution, while a midrash tells, that this same man died naturally on his bed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Define contradiction. Midrash will usually read something as metaphorical that may otherwise have been assumed to be literal, or read certain words more narrowly or broadly than they otherwise would have been, or posit certain miracles that aren't otherwise obvious from the text. If something goes against the "simple" meaning of a text but can be explained away even unintuitively, is that a contradiction?

Comment: The easiest thing you could do is tell us why you are asking, which is part of Mi Yodeya guidelines. It's a strange and random question, and would be more compelling as well as clear if we knew what made you think there might be contradictions, and why that is of interest?

Answer (score 2):

The first one that comes to mind is on the verse ([Genesis 37:24](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-37.htm#v24); quoted by [*Rashi* there](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-37.htm#v24)) "the pit was empty", commenting that it wasn't empty at all but had snakes and scorpions.

Another is the claim that Eden's "knowledge tree" was a wheat plant.  (To be fair, that's explained by saying that the Hebrew words for "tree" include wheat.  Still, I think we can call that contradicting the verse.)

Comment: I think this is not a contradiction. Tanakh talks about the absence of water. and doesn't negate that there might be other things inside the hole. plz edit your answer to add more examples, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Some midrashim are clearly explaining the verses. But some have some of "contradiction" to it, at least to its Pshat.Sometimes it's a big difference, sometimes it's not. Let's see some "big" differences:

For Midrashei Halacha, I would say the drasha that "An eye for an eye" is only money, or that the [pigul](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.7.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is when **thought** about eating it later.

For Midrashei Haggada, maybe the fact that Reuven didn't sleep with Bilha, and David did not commit adultery ?